# Why would this query run so slow?

Tags: mysql, sql, query-optimization, collation

I have two MySQL tables say A and B. A contains just one varchar column (lets call that one A1) with about 23000 records. Table B (70000 records) has some more columns, one of the corresponding with A1 from table A (lets call that one B1). I want to know which values in A are not in the corresponding column in B, so I use:

```
SELECT A1
FROM A
LEFT JOIN B
    ON A1 = B1
WHERE B1 IS NULL
```

Both columns A1 and B1 have indices defined on them. Still this query runs very slow. I've run explain, this is the output:

```
id  select_type table   type    possible_keys   key     key_len ref rows    Extra
1   SIMPLE      A       index   \N              PRIMARY 767     \N  23269   Using index
1   SIMPLE      B       ALL     \N              \N      \N      \N  70041   Using where; Not exists
```

UPDATE: `SHOW CREATE TABLE` for both tables (changed the original names);

```
CREATE TABLE `A` (
  `A1` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`A1`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8


CREATE TABLE `B` (
  `col1` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `col2` datetime NOT NULL,
  `col3` datetime default NULL,
  `col4` datetime NOT NULL,
  `col5` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  `col6` int(10) default NULL,
  `col7` int(11) default NULL,
  `col8` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `B1` varchar(255) default NULL,
  `col10` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  `col11` varchar(255) default NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`col1`),
  KEY `NewIndex1` (`B1`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=70764 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

'nother edit: `data_length` and `index_length` from `SHOW TABLE STATUS`

```
table   data_length index_length
A       465380      435200
B       5177996     1344512
```

Comment: Are you doing any indexing on the tables?

Comment: Funny thing, if I 'reverse' this, so do a RIGHT JOIN, only WHERE A1 IS NULL it finishes more quickly

Comment: Can you post profile results: `SET profiling=1; SELECT SQL_NO_CACHE A1 FROM A LEFT JOIN B ON A1 = B1 WHERE B1 IS NULL; SHOW PROFILE;`... this tells us exactly what step is utilizing most of the time. When I tested the above query with sample data (20000 + 70000 rows) I got response in < 0.1 sec.

Comment: I'm running it now. Only problem is that the query, as posted in my question, has not yet finished.. EDIT; when you tested the query, did you use varchar as column types? I've got a feeling that that is one of the reasons that this is taking so long...

Comment: @Lex: two tables with one varchar column each, indexed, populated with random strings, 4k strings exist in both tables. Besides profile info, please post the approx size of the two tables... is it in MBs or GBs? This matters in ways you cannot imagine.

Comment: I added the sizes of the tables to the question.

Comment: @lex: the query that took ~0.1 sec now takes forever to complete when I mixed the character sets, so have a look at my updated answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The character sets of the two columns that you are comparing in an OUTER JOIN differ. I am not sure if this is the cause so I tested and got these results:

```
SELECT A1
FROM A
LEFT JOIN B ON A1 = B1
WHERE B1 IS NULL

-- Table A..: 23258 rows, collation = utf8_general_ci
-- Table B..: 70041 rows, collation = latin1_swedish_ci
-- Time ....: I CANCELLED THE QUERY AFTER 20 MINUTES

-- Table A..: 23258 rows, collation = latin1_swedish_ci
-- Table B..: 70041 rows, collation = latin1_swedish_ci
-- Time ....: 0.187 sec

-- Table A..: 23258 rows, collation = utf8_general_ci
-- Table B..: 70041 rows, collation = utf8_general_ci
-- Time ....: 0.344 sec
```

Solution: make the character sets of the two tables (or the two columns atleast) same.

Comment: Yeah, it's a good point. Character set conversion for every row in a query may take much time.

Answer (score 1):

This query will scan all rows of table A, but if you have an index on B1 then most likely it will not scan table B:

```
select A1
from A
where not exists (
    select *
    from B
    where B.B1 = A.A1
)
```

Before running this or your original query you may try to run `ANALYZE TABLE` in order to update key distribution information for those tables:

```
ANALYZE TABLE A, B
```

If this doesn't help then you can try to play with indexes, for instance:

```
select A1
from A ignore index (PRIMARY)
where not exists (
    select *
    from B force index (NewIndex1)
    where B.B1 = A.A1
)
```

Comment: Indeed, EXPLAIN on this query does show type=index for both tables, but still "rows" just shows the total number of rows

Comment: @Lex Can you give a full `SHOW CREATE TABLE` output of those tables?

Comment: I've updated the original question with the output of `SHOW CREATE TABLE`

Comment: @Lex I have updated my answer. By the way, maybe you have many long and similar values in those columns, no?

Answer (score 0):

It seems *A1* and *B1* are large feilds.

> You created indices for both *A1* and *B1*

Make sure that they are indexed!

```
SELECT A1
FROM A
WHERE A1 NOT IN (
    SELECT B1 AS A1 From B;
)
```

Comment: humm... doesn't it break the logic of original query?

Comment: ? does it not produce the same result?

Comment: this will not produce the same result, and also runs very slow (hasn't finished after 5 minutes)

Comment: I am sure I have the indices. The query in your question will also take longer than the one with the `LEFT JOIN`

Answer (score 0):

try this query:

```
SELECT B1
FROM B
WHERE not B1  in (
  select A1
  from a
)
```

Comment: I've tried this before I had the LEFT JOIN, let it run for hours and it didn't finish...

Comment: This is definitely slower. Did you run an EXPLAIN before posting this answer?

Answer (score 0):

If I use your CREATE TABLES statements and run an EXPLAIN on your SELECT statement, I get this result:

```
id  select_type  table  type  possible_keys  key       key_len  ref  rows  Extra  
1   SIMPLE       A      index NULL           PRIMARY   767      NULL 2     Using index 
1   SIMPLE       B      index NULL           NewIndex1 258      NULL 4     Using where; Using index
```

On my MySQL version (5.1.41) the index is used as expected, so I think this might be an already fixed bug in MySQL assuming your index is set like in your create table statement posted. What MySQL version do you use?